# When are Strong Parameters used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I understand strong parameters are used in cases where we are creating an object and putting it into our database. For example,

`User.create(params[:user])` would have to be `User.create(params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)`.

This is standard and simple to understand, however, are strong parameters required when updating a column or a few attributes in a model?

`current_user.update_attributes(params[:user])`. Does that have to be `current_user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)`.

Lastly, I don't think it is needed for this case:

`current_user.update_column(authentication_token: nil)`, but would it have needed to be updated if instead we had `params = { authentication_token: nil }`, and did `current_user.update_column(params)`?

Answer (score 0):

I experimented on Rails 4 environment with both `update` and `update_attributes` method calls, and I received identical errors for both method calls: `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` `in` `PeopleController#update` . In the controller I used `@person.update(params[:person])` and `@person.update_attributes(params[:person])`; so that’s why it says `PeopleController` in the error message.

Based on the [API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes), it looks like in Rails 4 `update_attributes` is alias for `update`. So I guess `update_attributes` does the same thing as `update` method in Rails 4:

`update_attributes(attributes)` public

Alias for `ActiveRecord::Persistence#update`

Therefore, both `update` and `update_attributes` methods have to use strong parameters to update database. I also tested `update_attributes` method with strong parameters: `@person.update_attributes(person_parameters)` and it worked

**updated**

About `update_attribute` and `update_column` methods. I just tested those for the very first time through a controller, and with those methods you don’t need to use strong parameters inside of controller ( which was a bit surprise to me), even when you are using `params` (user provided values). So with `update_attribute` and `update_column` methods you can update database without using strong parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you pass an instance of ActionController::Parameters to one of the mass assignment apis (new, create, update_attributes, update etc.) you need to permit the appropriate fields.

In a controller the `params` method returns an instance of `ActionController::Parameters`, as are any hashes contained within it, so you need to use permit.

If you do

```
params = { foo: bar }
record.update_attributes(params) or

record.update_attributes(foo: bar)
```

Then you're passing a normal hash and so you don't need to use `permit`

Answer (score 0):

> Are strong parameters required when updating a column or a few
>   attributes in a model?

Yes, if the model is being updated with values from the end-user. **Never** trust the user input.

Suppose the current_user model has a 'role_id' column, which could be 1 for super user, 2 for normal user and 3 for guest. If you don't sanitize the parameters, the end-user could easily forge a request to gain privileges and compromise your application security.

Regarding your last question, you're right. You don't need strong parameters to update the record with values you already know.